# Loading view from UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

I made a UITableViewController and tried loading it the previous view

```
[self.view addSubview: poll_ridingController.view];
```

but when i run it, it display me a blank kid of thing where the footer was supposed to be.

See the attached Picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view you see IB just has what I like to call "eye-candy data" which means that Interface Builder does not implement any data into your project that is your job.  The methods you will need to make sure you implement are:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

For more information read the [Apple Documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)